# Shading regions of a contour plot with values above/below a certain value

Tags: plotting, filling

I have the following contour plot

```
Mpl = 1.22*10^(19)
Tplot = ContourPlot[Log10[0.5 1/(100)^(1/8) Sqrt[Mpl 10^x] (y)^(6/8)Exp[-(y)^3 1/8]], 
{x, -6, 16}, {y, 1, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

I would like to shade the regions of contours corresponding to values (for simplicity) > 10 and < -10. (The idea is that those regions are not allowed). I feel like there should be an easy way of doing this. The idea is as below
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica 12.1 has `HatchFilling` :

```
Mpl = 1.22*10^(19)
ContourPlot[
 Log10[0.5 1/(100)^(1/8) Sqrt[
    Mpl 10^x] (y)^(6/8) Exp[-(y)^3 1/8]], {x, -6, 16}, {y, 1, 10}
 , PlotLegends -> Automatic
 , FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}
 , ClippingStyle -> {HatchFilling[]}
 , PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image]

It can be superposed with the original plot :

```
 Mpl = 1.22*10^(19)
 Show[ContourPlot[
  Log10[0.5 1/(100)^(1/8) Sqrt[
     Mpl 10^x] (y)^(6/8) Exp[-(y)^3 1/8]], {x, -6, 16}, {y, 1, 10}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[
  Log10[0.5 1/(100)^(1/8) Sqrt[
     Mpl 10^x] (y)^(6/8) Exp[-(y)^3 1/8]], {x, -6, 16}, {y, 1, 10}(*,
  PlotLegends\[Rule]Automatic*),(*FrameLabel\[Rule]{"x","y"},*)
  ClippingStyle -> {HatchFilling[]}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-10, 10}}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z < -10 || z > 10]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty good. The only thing is when you superimpose in this way the two sets of contour lines don't agree. See for example there are two dark blue strips

Comment: problem mentionned in comment just above  ("superimpose... agree") corrected.